# Emails from email form goes to spam folder

Tags: php, html, forms, gmail, email-spam

Hi I have an email form in [my website](http://www.angelangeles.esy.es) which is working fine. It sends the mail to my Gmail however, Gmail marks those mails as spam.

It's an email form with an anti spam system found [here](http://nfriedly.com/techblog/2009/11/how-to-build-a-spam-free-contact-forms-without-captchas/).

My question is: how can I prevent mails sent from my contact form (or my future contact forms that are yet to be made) from being marked as spam by gmail or other email clients?

PS: I am writing this on mobile and I cannot upload the code yet. As soon as I hit the office I'll try to edit this and append the code.

Comment: What's the "From" email address you have in the PHP  header mail code? is it a valid email address?

Comment: yes, it is. However some emails are marked and some are not and they're from the same email. It drives me crazy.

Comment: Basically, Spam works on rating, Gmail and other providers check for suspecious activities, words, embeded media and much more to determine if something is spam. if other people marked the email as spam, it also has a weight. If you're sending on behalf of another email without proper auth, that could also be an issue. It's really tough to answer WHY this happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use a mailer class that implements an external SMTP server.
Gmail offers the posibility to use your gmail credentials on their SMTP.

That way you sent your e-mail from your website through your gmail account instead of the local mailserver without verified e-mail credentials.

Check for example PHPMailer:
https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Comment: My form goes like this: if they include their email address in the form, the 'from' will be from their account, else, my account will be used instead. Do you suggest that I use my email account all the time instead and then just include the 'from' to the body of the mail?

Comment: I would strongly discourage sending e-mails from accounts not being configured as their mailserver. So yes: use your account. (Mailservers block SPAM based on a lot of things nowadays. one of them is SPF records, meaning that if your server sends e-mail for my domain/emailadres, and it is not configured to do so, they will end up in SPAM)

Comment: Thanks for that. Glad to have someone that has do understanding in how email works.